# Implement Scan interface to read json array into map

Tags: arrays, json, go

I am fetching a JSON array from PostgreSQL, and I would like to read it into a map. I am able to Unmarshal the values into a `[]string` slice, but what I actually want is a `map[string]bool`.

I've written a custom type for the column with a Scan interface that converts the JSON array into a slice of strings first, then reads each string into the custom map type as keys.

```
type custMap map[string]bool

func (m *custMap) Scan(src interface{}) error {
  b, ok := src.([]byte)
  if !ok {
    return error(errors.New("Error Scanning Array"))
  }

  s := make([]string, 0)
  json.Unmarshal(b, &s)
  for _, v := range s {
    (*m)[v] = true
  }

  return nil
}


type data struct {
  vals custMap `json: "vals"`
}
```

The query I am trying to scan returns a row with a column vals which is a JSON array: `["some", "arr", "vals"]`, where the custom type is used like so:

```
var d models.data
sqlDB.QueryRow().Scan(&d.vals)
```

My expected output is a struct with the following shape

```
{ vals: map[string]bool { "some": true, "arr": true, "vals": true }
```

This compiles fine, but my code panics with "assignment to entry in nil map"

How can I fix my Scan function? Is it even possible to do this with a map type?

Comment: Please provide line numbers of the source and the error message. I suspect the error happens on the line `(*m)[v] = true` but that is just my suspicion.

Comment: Yes! that is where i'm getting 'assignment to entry in nil map'

Comment: The specific error thrown is 0http: panic serving [::1]:59847: assignment to entry in nil map.

I know it's that line because for my first try at this I did not use a pointer there:
    m[v] = true

Which resulted in this compile error:
invalid operation: m[v] (type *SCMap does not support indexing)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You are calling your method `Scan` of type `*custMap` on a unitialised map. Initialize `d.vals` either like

```
d.vals = custMap{}
```

or

```
d.vals = make(custMap)
```

Other answers already provide an explanation.

Answer (score 1):

> [The Go Programming Language Specification](https://golang.org/ref/spec)
>
> [Map types](https://golang.org/ref/spec#Map_types)
>
> A map is an unordered group of elements of one type, called the
>   element type, indexed by a set of unique keys of another type, called
>   the key type. The value of an uninitialized map is nil.
>
> A new, empty map value is made using the built-in function make, which
>   takes the map type and an optional capacity hint as arguments:
>
> ```
> make(map[string]int)
> make(map[string]int, 100)
> ```
>
> The initial capacity does not bound its size: maps grow to accommodate
>   the number of items stored in them, with the exception of nil maps. A
>   nil map is equivalent to an empty map except that no elements may be
>   added.

I don't see  a `make` to initialize your map: "A `nil` map is equivalent to an empty map except that no elements may be added."